# Why is my jquery code not being called?

Tags: jquery

This is my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
                    $('target').submit(function() 
                    {
                    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
                   });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="target" method="post">
            <input type="text" value="Hello there" />
            <input type="submit" value="Go" />
        </form>
        <div id="other">
        Trigger the handler
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @BNL - with your edit, the problem (and thus the solution) is no longer clear.  It was helpful (required, really) to see the full context so we knew he wasn't using document.ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always wrap your bind methods with the document ready function:

```
   <script>
   $(function () {

                $('#target').submit(function() 
                {
                alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
               });
    });
    </script>
```

*edit* the reason this is necessary is because if you try to bind it before the document is ready, there is a very good chance the #target object is not yet in existence.  Of course, you could change this to a $("#target").live("submit", function () {.... but, that's not a good idea for how to solve this problem.  Use the ready handler as I've shown above.

Comment: Note - I also added in the hash mark, as the others have mentioned.

Comment: Notice Jake added the '#' in your selector also.  That is part of the solution.  More info on the document ready function is at http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Comment: thanks guys I originally had a hash# but was playing around and removed it. The solution which Jake gave to wrap it in a document ready function worked. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that your selector is selecting a target tag, instead of an element with an id of target, so change this:

```
 $('target').submit(function()
```

to

```
 $('#target').submit(function()
```

Your second issue is that you should have your jQuery code wrapped around a DOM ready event.

Answer (score 0):

you missed a '#' sign.

```
<script>
                    $('#target').submit(function() 
                    {
                    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
                   });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the hash (#) tag for your selector.

```
$('#target').submit(function() 
...
```

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Because when this code is executed there is no target yet. Use [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Also it should be `$('#target')` as [id selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) should be prefixed with #.

```
$(function(){
    $('#target').submit(function() 
    {
        alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#` is missing in the selector.

```
$('#target').submit(function(){ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way:

```
 <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {

               $('#target').submit(function () {
                   alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
               });
           });
    </script>
```